# Capybara check if no selector has text of numbers greater than 500

Tags: capybara

I want to check if there are 0 instances of numbers greater than 500 in all of the rows of a table.

The table looks like this:

```
  <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
      <tr class="trip-row" data-categories= "<%= @categories.map(&:name).join(":") %>">
        <td id="ranking"><%= @trips.index(trip) + 1 %></td>
        <td id="trip-title"> <%= trip.title %> </td>
        <td><%= trip.departure_city %></td>
        <td><%= trip.arrival_city %></td>
        <td><%= trip.departure_airline %></td>
        <td><%= trip.short_description %></td>
        <td><%= trip.departure_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y, %I:%M") %></td>
        <td><%= trip.return_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y, %I:%M") %></td>
        <td><%= trip.price %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Details", real_trip_path(trip, info: { departure_date: trip.departure_date, return_date: trip.return_date, price: trip.price }), class: "btn btn-info" %></td>
      </tr>
 <% end %>
```

Can I write this:

```
within all(".trip-row") do  
    refute page has.content?   #number greater than 500?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate values in each cell rather than row by row.

```
page.all(.'trip-row td').each do |c|
  #evaluate here
end
```

You'll probably want to use regex to pull the numbers out from each cell, then evaluate from there using an rspec expectation.

Comment: is the evaluate supposed to be assert page.has_content?

Comment: You could try:

    c.text.to_i.should be < 500

Comment: Again, you'll probably have to massage some of the data you get back from each cell in order to properly evaluate.  Hope this helps!